# Sonar Analysis Not Working With Maven

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run mvn clean install sonar:sonar goal but it is failing with below error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project app: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to parse entry in bootstrap index: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> -> [Help 1]
```

Below is my maven,java and sonarqube version :

- Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5;
  2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
- Java version: 1.8.0_91
- SonarQubeVersion :7.0

Does anyone know the root cause and resolution for this issue?

Comment: Is your SonarQube server up and running? (for instance: can you log in to SonarQube?)

Comment: Yes it is up and running

Comment: Did you double check the "sonar.host.url" that is supposed to match your SonarQube server? Also, please include the full logs to help debug this. (you might use https://pastebin.com to provide your logs instead of flushing them into the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar